# CString : Find string contains all whitespaces

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I am trying to come up with a function that will look to see whether the given CString contains all white spaces.

The one i came up with below doesn't seem to work. Any suggestions?

```
BOOL IsAllWhiteSpace(CString str)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < str.GetLength(); i++)
    {
        char letter = str.GetAt(i);
        if (letter != ' ')
        {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: Suggest you try using !isspace (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y13z34da.aspx) rather than letter != '  '

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should explain what does it mean - "doesn't seem to work"

its wrong for empty string, and also it also does not include all white-space characters : (0x09 – 0x0D or 0x20). Below is a fixed version:

```
BOOL IsAllWhiteSpace(const CString& str)
{
  if (str.IsEmpty())
    return FALSE;
  for (int i = 0; i < str.GetLength(); i++)
  {
    char letter = str.GetAt(i);
    if (!_istspace(letter))
    {
      return FALSE;
    }
  }
  return TRUE;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite your function in one line:

```
return str.TrimLeft().IsEmpty();
```

Comment: This is bad idea, you modify `str`, this way your parameter must be `CString str` (you cannot use const CString&), which means copy is required on each function use - this means reallocations. TrimLeft according to docs does not work like `_istspace`, it does not remove whitespaces in the range (0x09 - 0x0D and 0x20 - space), but as in docs: `When used with no parameters, TrimLeft removes newline, space, and tab characters.`

Comment: It's "bad" only in your opinion. Yes, I *DO* modify the string, but original question did not pass a const reference. The modern MSDN help pages do not specify what characters are removed, but a quick test for TrimLeft() on CString s(" \x09 \x0A \x0B \x0C \x0D X"); removes everything in front of 'X'. My suggestion is good, because it takes advantage of existing functionality of the already used CString class; you do not need to design the code, test or debug it.

Comment: A little justification for -15 would be appreciated.